# How do I save a Silverlight 2.0 canvas to a database and export it to PDF

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, pdf

I have a Silverlight 2.0 project that allows a user to add text and images to a canvas.  They can move, rotate and resize the text/images.  I was wondering the best way to serialize the Silverlight objects to a database and also be able to generate a PDF of the canvas to be printed.

I've read some articles about calling a web-service and passing the serialized data, then saving and generating the PDF.  My main question is how to efficiently serialize the Silverlight objects so that they can be re-drawn when a user comes back and if there is a simple way to save the canvas as a PDF or image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are experiencing exactly the same problem while building out colaab, a Silverlight 2 collaboration system available at:

http://www.colaab.com

The options seem to be:

1. Create a server side process to open a web browser and setup the page correctly then take a screenshot of it using software like [WebShot](http://www.websitescreenshots.com/).
2. Send the Xaml from your visual tree to the server (theres a handy class in [SilverlightContrib](http://silverlightcontrib.org/) to get the Xaml from the object model). Once you get this on the server side use the fully fledged .NET frameworks WPF support to export this as a PNG. This is not supported on the server side as WPF is a client technology.
3. Use the HTML Bridge to call the browsers print function
4. Wait for Silverlight 3 - "better printing and RenderTargetBitmap (AKA bitmap screenshot) are two features that we're planning for the next version."

Thanks,

Bob

-- 
Bob Thomson
storm ideas

http://www.colaab.com
http://blog.stormideas.com
twitter: movingforwards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a simple way to save a canvas as a pdf or image.  We have had a similar problem recently and resorted to having a service running that essentially created an IE browser in memory hosting the silverlight app and then screenshotting it from there.  Is all a bit fiddly... I was hoping for something like Canvas.ToImage() ;)

Sorry there isn't a better answer!

I'll find out about serializing shortly.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I was hoping for something simple as well.  Let me know what you find out about the serialization.